# Syntax error defining function named "in"

Tags: elixir

How do I define a function named `in`? The obvious way produces a syntax error:

```
iex(1)> defmodule MyModule do
...(1)>   def in do
...(1)>   end
...(1)> end
** (SyntaxError) iex:2: syntax error before: do
```

Is this simply not possible because `in` is a reserved word?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`in` doesn't work with `def` directly because it's an operator, but a function in Elixir can have any name that can be converted to an atom, and `:in` is certainly a valid atom. There might be another way to do this, but the only one I know is to use `unquote(:in)` as the function name:

```
iex(1)> defmodule A do
...(1)>   def unquote(:in)(), do: :ok
...(1)> end
iex(2)> A.in
:ok
```